# Composer php error

Tags: yii2, composer, openserver

При попытке "развернуть" проект yii2 на пк, мне выдаёт ошибку

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for zelenin/string 0.0.1 -> satisfiable by 
zelenin/string[0.0.1].
- zelenin/string 0.0.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension 
intl is missing from your system.
Problem 2
- zelenin/string 0.0.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension 
intl is missing from your system.
- zelenin/yii2-slug-behavior 1.5.1 requires zelenin/string ~0.0.0 -> 
satisfiable by zelenin/string[0.0.1].
- Installation request for zelenin/yii2-slug-behavior 1.5.1 -> satisfiable 
by zelenin/yii2-slug-behavior[1.5.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- D:\sergej\openserver\ospanel\modules\php\PHP-7.2-x64\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by 
PHP in CLI mode.
```

`php --ini` Выдаёт

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         
D:\sergej\openserver\ospanel\modules\php\PHP-7.2-x64\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Как можно решить эти ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка оставалась из-за того что я раскомментировал временный фаил.

Решение проблемы:

```
Зайти в меню -> Дополнительно -> Конфигурация -> PHP<br>
Откроется файл конфигурации<br>
Найти строку "extension=php_intl.dll"<br> 
Убрать ";" в начале строки -> Сохранить <br>
Перезапустить сервер<br>
Ошибка должна исчезнуть<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас не установлено расширение `intl` для php

Comment: Если вы говорите про настройку openserver'a (Т.е убрать точку с запятой - разкоментировать) то это не помогает, пробывал. Или мне нужно именно установить? В таком случае можете подсказать команду? или дать ссылку на информацию( я не смог найти )

Comment: Написано же `requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension 
intl is missing from your system`: для php не установлено расширение `intl`. Значит что-то не так делаете. https://toster.ru/q/432549

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.